# disable wordpress to ask for login credentials

Tags: wordpress

i got a message while uploading a plugin "To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host."

I want to disable this message as i dont have login credentials of ftp panels.How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress displays that message [when it doesn't have permission](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress) to write to its own files directly. My [Upgrade First Aid](https://github.com/daveross/upgrade-first-aid) plugin can help identify which permissions need to change.